# Linq null value not comparing

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

Scenario is that I need to check each column of a row to see if it contains a userID. I only want to be able to insert a userID into a column if it does NOT exist in any other column.

Table is like:

```
Col1 = ID (PK)
Col2 = No1 varchar(50) ..... also tried GUID
Col3 = No2 varchar(50) ..... also tried GUID
Col4 = No3 varchar(50) ..... also tried GUID
```

Default value of each column is null bar the ID which is auto.

So current state of the table is:

```
1  NULL  NULL  NULL
2  NULL  NULL  NULL
3  NULL  2     NULL
```

What I want to do is insert the userID value into the selected column on the proviso that the userID does not exist in any of the other columns.

I tried the following:

```
mymodel m = new mymodel()
m = db.mytable.Where(t => 
t.id == id && 
t.No1 != userID &&
t.No2 != userID &&
t.No3 != userID).First();
```

The idea is to check for an entry first and then run an update.

Now when I run this and all columns are null I get nothing back.
When I run it on row 3 (which has userID in col 2) I also get nothing.

If this was SQL straight I would likely put an isnull(userID, '') wrapper on the userID, but as far as I am aware this is not possible in Linq.

I cannot check for NULL (i.e. t.No2 != userID && t.No2 == NULL) because this means that I will be able to insert a userID into a row that already has said userID already in another column.

Is my only option to design the database to have a default value of '' in each of the columns to enable Linq to compare NULL?

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand, but shouldn't your check be `(t.No2 != userID || t.No2 == NULL)`

Comment: I'm totally confused with what that model is supposed to represent .. would it be better if normalized from columns to rows?

Comment: That's quite a scenario you've got there :)

Comment: As explained ... if I include the t.No2 == Null it will allow me to enter the userID into that column even if the userID exists in another column within the row

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so my original logic works if I assign a default value to each column of ''.

The NULL is not compared in the Linq ... but the empty string is.

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding, but normally one could do something along the lines of:

```
mymodel m = new mymodel()
m = db.mytable.Where(t => 
t.id == id && 
(t.No1 == null || t.No1 != userID) &&
(t.No2 == null || t.No2 != userID) &&
(t.No3 == null || t.No3 != userID)).First();
```

I believe doing an explicit null check on each column might be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the UserID has a value first:

```
mymodel m = new mymodel()
m = db.mytable.Where(t => 
t.id == id && (!userId.HasValue ||
(t.No1 != userID.Value &&
t.No2 != userID.Value &&
t.No3 != userID.Value))).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write compare function like

```
public bool Compare(ColmunNo1DataType colValue, UserIdDataType userId){...}
```

and use next LINQ code

```
mymodel m = new mymodel()
m = db.mytable.Where(t => 
t.id == id && 
Compare(t.No1,userID) &&
Compare(t.No2,userID) &&
Compare(t.No3,userID)).First();
```

Comment: Linq to entities won't accept this query because it doesn't know how to translate `Compare()` into SQL.